# How to deselect a single multi-selection point in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, code-editor

I am finding I often will multi-select a bunch of single points (ctrl+click on the point) in Sublime Text 2, get to the end of the items I want to multi-select and then discover one in the middle of them all that should not have been selected.

I then have to cancel the multi-select (esc key) and start my selection all over.

Is there a way to deselect a single multi-select point?  I looked all over the net and experimented with the traditional opposite items such as ctrl+shift+click on the point I want to deselect.  No joy.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this one:

<kbd>alt</kbd> + Middle Mouse Button

this feature/shortcut is called subtract from selection.

Comment: I just forgot to say that, on OS X (Mac), you should use Command+Shift instead of Alt.

Comment: And what if I'm using the trackpad and have no middle mouse button?

Answer (score 12):

In OSX <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+ left click removes an added multi-cursor.

Comment: Just ⌘+shift + left click  is enough

Answer (score 5):

On Linux, if you are using a touchpad, try using: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right-Click</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only one option working for me in Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are on OSX, you need to disable `drag_text`.

Edit your user preferences, i.e. `super + ,` and add this:

```
"drag_text": false
```

Otherwise, you can select just like before - `ctrl + click` (`command + click`), and to deselect an instance you use `alt + click` (`command + shift + click`).

Comment: Upvote because this does work, but is not the best answer for my use as it also disables the ability to drag and drop sections of code.  So if I want the convenience of alt+click to deselect a multi-selection point the trade off is no drag and drop.  This is a good solution for someone who may not have a three-button mouse.  But, as I do have one, the solution from Hugo Corra is the best answer.  Thanks so much for your solution!

Comment: Made my answer relevant to both OSX and Windows users.

Comment: If you are saying that in windows you just alt + click to subtract from the selection without having to disable draft_text, just an FYI that does not work.  alt+middle button click does work in Windows, but not just alt+click (i.e. traditional left button click)

Answer (score 3):

To deselect any text region (this way also deselects any included cursor point(s)):

**On Windows**

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right_Mouse_Button</kbd> *(Drag-Select what you need to deselect)*

OR: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Middle_Mouse_Button</kbd> *(Drag-Select what you need to deselect)*

**On OSX**

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Left_Mouse_Button</kbd> *(Drag-Select what you need to deselect)*

OR: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Middle_Mouse_Button</kbd> *(Drag-Select what you need to deselect)*

This works on SublimeText 2/3.

In case you want to deselect a single cursor point (not a region), you can do the same and drag-select any region that includes that cursor point. [Example: My Wor`[Cursor]`d. To deselect the cursor you can drag-select on: r`[Cursor]`d (or any region including the cursor) and it will automatically deselect the cursor point.]

Source: [Column Selection](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/column_selection.html)